# Webkit gradient text showing up as solid block on android

Tags: android, text, webkit

I'm using a webkit gradient for text with a fallback to a solid color but on android it just shows up as one solid block of gradient. Is there a way to make this work on the android o/s or make it at least use the solid color fallback?

```
color:#eaeaea;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F4F4F4), to(#555));
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```